# How do I watch the element size on load AND resize of the window with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to resize the height of a `<div id="main">something</div>` automatically so that even when it's empty, it has a min-height of the full screen height minus the header. It's working on load but not the resize. If I resize, I have to refresh the screen for it to recalcalculate. I'd love to have this watch the screen so that it resizes on-the-fly. How can I do this with my current code or a different approach?

```js
let main = document.getElementById('main');
let fullscreen = window.innerHeight;
let headerHeight = document.getElementById('navHeader').offsetHeight;
let newsletterHeight = document.getElementById('newsletter').offsetHeight;
let footerHeight = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
let addHeight = headerHeight + newsletterHeight + footerHeight;
let computedHeight = fullscreen - addHeight + 7;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('main').style.cssText = `min-height:${computedHeight}px;`;
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  document.getElementById('main').style.cssText = `min-height:${computedHeight}px;`;
});
```

In my code, I am grabbing the window innerHeight, the header height, a newsletter element height that is flushed under the header, and the footer height. Adding it all together. Then computer the remainder as my main body real estate. This is the element that resizes depending on the size and calculations.

Here is the HTML of a blank page is you need it, (ignore the PHP inclusions)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fitness & Lifestyle | Contact</title>
    <?php include ('./partials/header.php') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include ('./partials/nav.php') ?>

    <section class="mt-7" id="newsletter">
      <?php include ('./partials/newsletter.php') ?>
    </section>
    <section id="main"></section>


    <?php include ('./partials/footer.php') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use CSS? Handling layout is one of the big reasons it exists in the first place.  `:root { --hheight: 300px; } header { height: var(--hheight); } #main { min-height: calc(100vh - var(--hheight)); }`? And bonus points: even with scripts blocked, your page will layout correctly now.

Comment: Probably the header has no fixed height. I hope not, anyway..

Comment: If it's a header, I certainly hope it is, so that it's consistent across all pages that share the header. Because as site owner you _know_ what's in your header.

Comment: But you don't know how the browser will render the fonts and some other twicks that you'll prefer the browser will do its calculation for the height..

Comment: All great points! I guess I didn't think about that. I can do it with CSS. I had it that way. I was experimenting with the JS resize to compare. But you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you calculate the `computedHeight` only once in the page load. Every time you the resize handler is firing, `computedHeight` is the same value.

You need to re-calculate it in every resize. Something like this:

```js
function resizeMain() {
  let main = document.getElementById('main');
  let fullscreen = window.innerHeight;
  let headerHeight = document.getElementById('navHeader').offsetHeight;
  let newsletterHeight = document.getElementById('newsletter').offsetHeight;
  let footerHeight = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
  let addHeight = headerHeight + newsletterHeight + footerHeight;
  let computedHeight = fullscreen - addHeight + 7;
  document.getElementById('main').style.cssText = `min-height:${computedHeight}px;`;
}

calculateHeight();
window.addEventListener('load', resizeMain);
```

Although, I'm not sure it's a wise approach because for each resize you'll do some heavy calculation. You may want to use some kind of [`debounce`](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) function.